how to change the method return type of a class in Typescript
I have a linked list set of interfaces, with a .prev and .next properties. Its "value is typed in inherited interfaces;
the Parent Type "Branch" has a .next and .prev  properties that are of type BranchIF (interface).
There is a BranchObj class that iplements BranchObjIF; BranchObjIF extends BranchIF.
However in the class BranchObj and the interface BranchObjIF I want the next and prev properties to be of type BranchObjIF - not the generic BranchIF.
Is this possible? when and where can I suppress typescript errors around this?

Please provide a [mre] as a plaintext code sample instead of as a description of code. It's much easier for us to suggest something if we can test it first, and right now in order to test it we'd need to try to convert your verbal description into actual code. It would be much better if you'd do that instead for us.

It is kind of hard to know for sure if this is what you are looking for If you don't share some code. However, with the information that you have provided my understanding is that what you are looking for requires some generic type <T>. It would be something like the following:
interface BranchIF<T> {
    next: T | null;
    prev: T | null;
}

class Branch implements BranchIF<Branch> {
  constructor(
    public next: BranchIF<Branch> | null,
    public prev: BranchIF<Branch> | null
  ) {}
}

interface BranchObjIF extends BranchIF<BranchObjIF> {

}

class BranchObj implements BranchObjIF {
  constructor(
    public next: BranchIF<BranchObj> | null,
    public prev: BranchIF<BranchObj> | null
  ) {}
}

const branch = new Branch(null, null);
type x = typeof branch.next; // BranchIF<Branch> | null


const branchObj = new BranchObj(null, null);
type y = typeof branchObj.next; // BranchIF<BranchObj> | null

